# I installed OpenJDK, now I'm installing Tomcat. Where is the JRE?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm installing Tomcat 8. It is requiring a JRE:

[image: Tomcat requiring JRE path]

I installed OpenJDK for Windows. I did some Googling and got conflicting results of whether or not the JDK has the JRE inside it. I also got something that said the JDK is the JRE, so I'm confused.

I did standard installation of OpenJDK. As far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDK comes bundled with a JRE. This means that whenever you install the JDK it also installs a JRE.

As to where is the JRE. Please look inside the folder where JDK is installed.
Normally for windows the path looks something like:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8u222-b10\jre
```

However, it is still possible to install the JRE separately also.

Update:

If your installation doesn't look like this, you may be able to do

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

or

```
which java
```

To get the location of your jre. OP says the jre location was the same as JAVA_HOME, not the bin folder...

Comment: My installation doesn't look like that. Maybe I did it wrong. I don't have a `jre` folder, nor the `jdk8u...` folder. But I can do `java -version` and not get an error.

Comment: In order to find where is your java installed. Please try `which java` in cmd and you will know where is your jre installed

Comment: `echo %JAVA_HOME%` gives me `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.212.04-hotspot\`

Comment: Aaaand, ok I see jre in there. Thanks!

Comment: OK, so is the Java Virtual Machine Path to `jre` or `jre/bin`?

Comment: Normally `jre/bin`.

Comment: Turns out it was the same as JAVA_HOME... Seems like Tomcat should've been able to figure that out...